# How to find volume of the region $\{(x,y,z)|\,0 \le (x-1)^2+y^2 \le z(1-z)\}$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

I need to find the volume of the region :

$$R=\{(x,y,z)| \space 0 \le (x-1)^2+y^2 \le z(1-z)\}$$

I don't understand the region. Is it the volume outside the cylinder and inside a sphere? Can you give me some hints in order to set up the integral?

**Answer** : $\frac{\pi}{6}$

Comment: It looks like you have a sphere.  Expand the right side, bring the $z$ terms to the other side, complete the square, and you will have what is recognizably the equation of a sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left inequality is always true for sum of squares is greater than zero.

The right inequality represents a sphere of radius $\frac{1}{2}$.  Hence the volume of the region is $\frac{4}{3}\pi(\frac{1}{2})^3 = \frac{\pi}{6}$.